# Nuxt 3 connection with postgresql

Tags: python, node.js, postgresql, web-scraping, nuxt3

My final goal is a "webapp" that can scrape some restaurant daily menus and I'm using GitHub actions as a backend and I want a simple frontend with nuxt3. Therefore, in this method I think I don't need a "real" backend because the GitHub actions can scrape the pages, load them into postgres and repeat them once a week (cronjob) and then query and display them on the frontend and that's it. All it needs is a connection between the frontend and the database. So my last step was the frontend and I found an easy way but it didn't work for me because I couldn't access the database in the frontend.

So as I said, I want to connect to postgresql via nuxt3. I have a completely virgin nuxt3 project anyway. (Here is a [nuxt3-tailwind tutorial](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs#standard).) After that, I found that [tutorial](https://a4u.medium.com/nuxt-3-connection-with-postgresql-bdbc347fd09a), but I got an error that "plugin.apply is not a function". Does anyone have a solution for this or maybe another method?

```
 WARN  Plugin C:/Vscode/nuxt/third/plugins/db.js is not wrapped in defineNuxtPlugin. It is advised to wrap your plugins as in the future this may enable enhancements.
 [nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] plugin.apply is not a function
 at C:\Vscode\nuxt\third\virtual:nuxt:C:\Vscode\nuxt\third\.nuxt\plugins\server.mjs:34:89
 at Module.executeAsync (/C:/Vscode/nuxt/third/node_modules/unctx/dist/index.mjs:111:19)
 at setup (C:\Vscode\nuxt\third\virtual:nuxt:C:\Vscode\nuxt\third\.nuxt\plugins\server.mjs:34:65)
 at C:\Vscode\nuxt\third\node_modules\nuxt\dist\app\nuxt.js:115:60
 at fn (C:\Vscode\nuxt\third\node_modules\nuxt\dist\app\nuxt.js:163:44)
 at Object.callAsync (/C:/Vscode/nuxt/third/node_modules/unctx/dist/index.mjs:68:55)
 at C:\Vscode\nuxt\third\node_modules\nuxt\dist\app\nuxt.js:165:56
 at Object.runWithContext (C:\Vscode\nuxt\third\node_modules\@vue\runtime-core\dist\runtime-core.cjs.js:3863:18)
 at callWithNuxt (C:\Vscode\nuxt\third\node_modules\nuxt\dist\app\nuxt.js:165:24)
 at C:\Vscode\nuxt\third\node_modules\nuxt\dist\app\nuxt.js:35:54
```

Answer (score 1):

What the guy does in the tutorial is not a "plugin, but an "utility". I am not sure why he thinks this works, or how he made it working.

What I'd suggest you should do is to delete the plugin definition from Nuxt config and move your `db.js` into `/utils` directory. Like this Nuxt will auto-import `client` (it just does that for all exports placed in `/utils` out of the box), so will be able to use it anywhere around your application without explicit importing.

---

To define something as a Nuxt plugin, however, your file should look like this:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  // Doing something with nuxtApp
})
```

(taken from the [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins))

Thats also what the error message complains about. So what you would need to do to have your DB connection as a plugin, is to adjust `~/plugins/db.js` to look like this. But I can't tell you then, how to register your `client` inside this plugin to be available throughout your Nuxt application. Probably there is a solution, but unknown to me right now.